# Firebase Database Rules Using an unspecified index

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am struggling with what seems to be a very trivial task. I am receiving the following warning from Firebase when doing a simple query:

**Query:**

```
admin.database().ref('/dispatch/')
    .orderByChild('shipmentKey')
    .equalTo(shipmentKey)
    .once('value')
    .then(
```

**Warning:**

> FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "shipmentKey" at /dispatch to your security rules for better performance

My database looks like the following:
[image]

And my database.rules.json looks like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "dispatch": {
      ".indexOn": "shipmentKey"
    }
  }
}
```

and have also tried:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "dispatch": {
      ".indexOn": ["shipmentKey"]
    }
  }
}
```

I have already read all the other stackoverflow questions on this topic and cannot seem to rid our project of this warning, any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

**UPDATE 06/22/2017**

I have solved the problem, and it was very simple. It turns out that firebase deploy wasn't actually deploying the database rules so the database.rules.json was not being uploaded. I simply ran the following command:

```
firebase deploy --only database
```

And everything works great now! Thanks to Bob Snyder for helping point this out. Hope this helps someone else out there!

Comment: Your rules looks okay.  Are you sure they're in effect for the database?  When you look at the rules in the Firebase console, do you see the rules you posted?

Comment: They aren't there Bob, not sure why, any ideas?

Comment: I edit my rules directly in the Firebase Console.  Are you deploying yours using the [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#deployment)?  Given that your rules are simple, you could try updating them using Firebase Console to see if that resolves the problem.  I suspect it will.  Don't know why the CLI might not be working for you--haven't used it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put all the indexes in square brackets, separated by a comma if you have more than one.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "dispatch": {
      ".indexOn": ["shipmentKey"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bradley, I have tried that as well, still does not work :(